# How to set the combination of two colums to be unique?

Tags: sqlite, database-design

I have a question about DB modeling, I have a table created as following:

```
CREATE TABLE "users_articles" 
  ("id"         INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
   "article_id" INTEGER,
   "user_id"    INTEGER)
```

1. Which statement will alter this table, so that the combination of article_id and user_id is unique?
2. Which statement tells me, if the DB has already been altered?

Thanks,

Markus

Comment: This has nothing to do with UML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to create unique index:

   `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_users_articles ON users_articles (article_id, user_id)`
2. Please clarify why you need it?
   **UPDATE:**
   Use `IF NOT EXISTS` to ignore index creation if it already exists:

   `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS unique_users_articles ON users_articles (article_id, user_id)`

Comment: Thanks for the solution for my first Question! The second: As I make a update on a mobile application I need to prove whether the locale db already has gotten this change on unique index.